# Laravel newly added javascript files give an error net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

In my laravel application, it gives an error with a *net:: ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)*. I have added the javascript files into the

> resources\assets\js\customjsfile.js

.

And I'm calling the file like this.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/customjsfile.js')  }}"></script>
```

Other js files such as app.js are loading.

Comment: the file would have to end up in `public/js/` for you to reach it via a URL

Comment: that means?i don't clear.normally as i know, in laravel once we put them in the assets folder and when calling through the asset() helper, it automatically sets the url path.

Comment: no ... it would have to be in `public` for you to be able to reach it as every other folder is outside the document root

Comment: ok, so then i can't use asset() helper is it?

Comment: you can't use any URL helper because the file is not accessible from any URL unless it is in the public folder, the document root is the public folder, nothing else is accessible ... good luck

Comment: You can use laravel mix to copy paste and mange other asset files. I have already explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asset()` function takes path from the `/public` folder by default. if you are using laravel mix then you should update your `webpack.mix.js` file otherwise you can directly put the file in `/pubilc/js` folder.

In webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/js/customfile.js', 'public/js');
```

Then run

```
npm run dev // for development
npm run production // for production
```

for this

> "Other js files such as app.js are loading."

`app.js` file is already defined in the `webpack.mix.js`